# Select does not work after inserting options with html() after ajax call (Bootstrap Selectpicker)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

This is the select:

```
<select class="selectpicker" id="item-fornecedores-1" multiple data-placeholder="Selecione os fornecedores para este item"></select>
```

This is the data that I insert:

```
<optgroup label="São José do Rio Preto"><option>TORQUEMIX </option></optgroup><optgroup label="Sorocaba"><option>A.M.DIB INDUSTRIA E COMERCIO</option></optgroup><optgroup label="Salto de Pirapora"><option>CONTA DE TESTE DE ÓRGãO PúBLICO</option></optgroup>
```

Which is generated by:

```
    $response = "";
    foreach ($filtro as $key => $value) {
        $nomeCidade = getResults("SELECT nome FROM tbl_cidades WHERE id = '".$key."'")[0]["nome"];
        if (strpos($response, $nomeCidade) === false) {
            $response .= '<optgroup label="'.$nomeCidade.'">';
        }
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($value); $i++) {
            $nomeFornecedor = getResults("SELECT nome_fantasia FROM tbl_fornecedors WHERE id = '".$value[$i]."'")[0]["nome_fantasia"];
            $response .= '<option>'.$nomeFornecedor.'</option>';
        }
        $response .= '</optgroup>';
    }
```

And here's where the select gets updated on success:

```
                $.ajax({
                    url: hostGlobal+"site/estrutura/ajax.php",
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "TEXT",
                    data: {
                        action: "filtrarFornecedores",
                        prefeitura_id: <?=$_SESSION["id"]?>,
                        tipo_negocio: 1,
                        segmentos: $("#pedido-segmento").val(),
                        estados: $("#pedido-fornecedor-estado").val(),
                        index: (i+1).toString()
                    },
                    success:function(result, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                        console.log(JSON.parse(result)[1]);
                        $("#item-fornecedores-" + JSON.parse(result)[0]).html(JSON.parse(result)[1]);
                        $("#item-fornecedores-" + JSON.parse(result)[0]).show();
                    },
                    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    //  console.log(errorThrown);
                    }
                });
```

The select element gets updated, but this is what happens:

[image]

And if I don't use show() afterwards, I see no data at all (And the HTML is perfectly valid, since this same result works when I use it directly on the HTML document).

I'm using [bootstrap-select](https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/). Why I can't update / "load" those options in "real-time" without screwing the whole element?

EDIT:

I've just realized it works perfectly when I remove the "multiple" from the select tag. Nevertheless, I **really** need to use multiple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call the [refresh](https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/methods/#refresh) method after modifying the data to make it work.

> To programmatically update a select with JavaScript, first manipulate
>   the select, then use the refresh method to update the UI to match the
>   new state. This is necessary when removing or adding options, or when
>   disabling/enabling a select via JavaScript.

```
$("#item-fornecedores-" + JSON.parse(result)[0]).selectpicker('refresh');
```

When you call `show()`, you are forcing the underlying select element to be visible. The select is actually replaced by elements generated by the widget.